# Progress - How to concatenate many rows with same id in sql?

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

My table contains those values :

```
NODOS PROCEDURE PHASE
  1     CXP      PRB
  1     CXP      PEX
```

And I want this :

```
NODOS PROCEDURE PHASE
  1     CXP      PRB, PEX
```

I use the progress database. Everything I've tried doesn't work (String_AGG, Group_concat...) because it's a special database. Does anyone have any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Does Progress support those functions? Apparently not https://community.progress.com/s/article/000045898.

Comment: Progress doesn't support thoses functions